# SQL Server: will an INSTEAD OF trigger affect referential integrity checks?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, triggers

I would like to set a foreign key to null if what it refers to doesn't exist. However, I would like all the other referential integrity checks to work as normal.

Will an `INSTEAD OF` trigger force me to write all the integrity checks?

Since triggers cannot change the inserted table and data cannot exist in the target table because of referential integrity, is there a way to null these foreign keys so that records can save?

EDIT: The biggest mistake I made is not knowing that the database won't make any changes if an `INSTEAD OF` trigger exists.  The trigger must make the changes to the table itself.

Comment: Approaches exist that don't involve deleting (possibly valuable) data. Why would you want to set a CustomerID field, say, to NULL in an Orders record, merely so you could save the order record? Wouldn't it be better to create dummy records in the Customers table for all order.customerids that do not exist there? That would permit the order record to be saved while preserving the data you want to delete merely so you can save the record. How did you establish the foreign key constraint in the first place if there were order.customerids that did not exist in Customer table?

Comment: Chicken and egg problem: One user creates a list of products, then another user gets a list of products slightly after.  Before the second user saves their references, the first user deleted those products.  We want the second to save, but we don't want to refer to missing products.

Comment: You do not want to save the record with no valid reference, you want to return an error. Sacrificing data integrity is a bad idea. If the product no longer exists, user2 needs to be told.

Comment: @Dr Zim: User A selects products, then user B selects products, then user A deletes some of those products, so that user B's list is no longer current, and when user B goes to insert, say, an order record, referring to one of those deleted  products, the RI constraint causes user B's insert to fail?

Comment: @Tim, A creates products, B uses them but in the meanwhile A deleted them.  B needs to save records so that FKs are null if targets don't exist.  B cannot "reload" A records during the assembly of B records but can reload B records to see missing references and fix them.  B may not be the same person fixing them.  We thought about dropping the ref integrity, but it's worse to refer to products that don't exist than to refer to nothing in our case.

Comment: @HLGEM I agree, but in this case it's one or two records out of a few hundred that cause the insert to fail.  It would be easy to call these to the user's attention after saving.  They want to use a bulldozer to get most of the items, then use shovels to clean up later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Catcall points out, the `ON DELETE SET NULL` referential action does what you appear to want.

That said, yes you can write an `INSTEAD OF` trigger to do the same (or a variation on a theme) without having to take care of all the referential integrity constraints yourself. Here's a brief example:

Tables and test data:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE T2 (ID INTEGER REFERENCES T1 (ID));

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (1), (2), (3), (2), (3), (3);
```

The trigger:

```
-- 'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first statement in a batch.
CREATE TRIGGER tr__T1__instead_of_delete
ON T1
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN;

UPDATE T2
   SET ID = NULL
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                  FROM deleted
                 WHERE deleted.ID = T2.ID
              );

DELETE
  FROM T1
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                  FROM deleted
                 WHERE deleted.ID = T1.ID
              );

END;
```

Test the trigger:

```
DELETE 
  FROM T1 
 WHERE ID = 3;
```

Comment: +1 for not having to check references when an instead of trigger exists.  Now if `instead of` runs before data changes and inserted and deleted views are read only, how would you correct the data to be saved so that bad foreign keys are set to null?  Would this invalid record exist in the target table at the time the trigger fires and fail the transaction after the trigger executes, removing that record?

Comment: It just occurred to me that if the `INSTEAD OF` trigger did nothing, no records would change.  LOL.

Comment: So your answer is really the answer, just using an insert/update instead of trigger to null the values just before like in your example.

Answer (score 2):

If a foreign key is nullable, you can use `ON DELETE SET NULL`, which will update the foreign key to NULL if the referenced row is deleted.

`ON DELETE SET DEFAULT` is another possibility, depending on your application.

Comment: it's slightly different.  If one person creates a product, then another tries to refer to it but before they save, the first deletes the product, we would want the second to save with null values (the product doesn't exist to refer to it when the second saves.) In your example, it seems the second person successfully saved, then the references are set to null when the products delete.

Comment: You can test how the COMMIT statements work this by opening two shells. I'm not sure I understand your concern, since the end result of both scenarios would be identical--a NULL instead of a value. In PostgreSQL, for example, the DELETE statement won't commit until a previously started INSERT commits.

Comment: The trouble is the second record won't save because the first doesn't exist.  However, I missed that the presence of a `INSTEAD OF` trigger turns off the normal data persistence, leaving the trigger itself to do the actual insert/update command.

Comment: @Dr. Zim: Is that based on your understanding of transactions, or is it based on actual testing? You seem to be saying that, in essence, a DELETE statement that's started *after* an INSERT will always commit *before* that INSERT statement. I don't have a SQL Server instance running here, but I'm not sure you're right about that.